# Using Kotlin and buildSrc for build.gradle Won't Show Available Library Version Updates?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

As the title mentions, I am using buildSrc and Kotlin for Gradle Dependency management in a modularized android project as per the following tutorial: 
https://caster.io/lessons/gradle-dependency-management-using-kotlin-and-buildsrc-for-buildgradle-autocomplete-in-android-studio

it's working all fine but the question is how can I be notified if there are any libraries that have an update on their version? (i am not getting the notification on the library where it gets marked showing that there is an update)

is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Very diligent capitalisation in the title - can you apply same (and spelling like *it's*) to the question body?

Comment: I'm not aware of a tool that checks that you use the latest greatest version of a library. The [OWASP dependency check](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check) can warn you if used libraries have known security problems.

Comment: @Robert a library is marked and a hint is shown when you place your cursor on it informing you that a new version of the library is available for you to change the version number... i'm actually surprised with your comment unless you didn't understand my question

Comment: I'm actually facing that problem too. Using Kotling for Gradle is great, but I really miss Android Studio telling me that there are new versions of the library I'm using, if you find a solution for this please let me know.

Comment: @Rashad.Z You got any solution for this?

Comment: @Rethinavel no actually i stopped using it when i didnt find a solution back then

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you can take here:

1. Leave out the dependencies in `build.gradle`. Currently, there is no hint shown in Android Studio if you extract out them into variables. So you can just use strings here.
2. Use [Gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) to check for dependency updates. You can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@kasem./how-to-check-version-updates-when-you-are-using-buildsrc-way-of-organizing-gradle-dependencies-5e659186c803).

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `buildSrc`, Use Kotlin DSL custom plugins as in official Google example https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/tree/main/build-logic

for libs we can use Gradle Version Catalog for all modules https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/gradle/libs.versions.toml (it's added in the `build-logic` separate project https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/build-logic/settings.gradle.kts)